# PowerShell sending keystrokes e.g. F5 after opening an application

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell to open an application and then send keystrokes F5, which is "Running", just like someone presses the F5 keyboard to start the shortcut.

However, [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}") is not working, I don't know if it is the right sentence or not?

```
Start-Process "C:\Users\minnie\Documents\Ixia\IxLoad\Repository\HTTP Concurrent conns port1n2.rxf"

Start-Sleep -s 50

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}")

exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not the best way but you can try something like :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
start-process notepad
$p=get-process | where {$_.name -eq "notepad"}
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($p.ID)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("~Name:{TAB}$env:UserName~")
# [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}{ENTER}")
```

You should also look at that extension :
http://wasp.codeplex.com/